# RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (2.0.1) or chardet (5.1.0)/charset_normalizer (3.1.0) doesn't match a supported version

Tags: python

My script was running fine before, but now it is giving me this error:

```
RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (2.0.1) or chardet (5.1.0)/charset_normalizer (3.1.0) doesn't match a supported version
```

I have read existing posting and tried the following, but they did not work:

```
>pip3 install requests
```

and

```
>pip3 install --upgrade requests
```

The first command produced the following:

```
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.29.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (96 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Using cached certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2022.12.7 charset-normalizer-3.1.0 idna-3.4 requests-2.29.0 urllib3-1.26.15
```

Then when I tried the second command, it produced this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (2.29.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2022.12.7)
```

But I am still getting the warning.  Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Urllib3, you have v2.0, but need below 1.27.

Comment: Isn't there a pip that supports above 1.27?

Comment: Why do you need another pip ? You could install any version of the package 'pip install  urllib3==1.26'